# 'op_invalid_limit' error trying to send asset

Tags: assets

I'm trying to send an asset on testnet and I'm getting this error: `op_invalid_limit`. What could this mean?

Comment: StackExchange blocks too short questions intentionally. You haven't provided any source code, only a vague error description. In most cases it's not enough to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: yes, of course that's why it was done. I've intentionally not provided any source code as I'm using an SDK built on top of Stellar's SDK - it would not be helpful to anyone. I was *hoping* this issue could be gleaned from the error code, which - as you've correctly pointed out - is rather vague. thanks for the edit and the answer, I'll dig on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all possible errors for operations in [List of Operations](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#change-trust) doc.

```
CHANGE_TRUST_INVALID_LIMIT  -3  This operation would drop the limit of this trustline below the amount of the asset the account currently holds.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to invoke the [`Change Trust`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/operation.html#change-trust) operation while providing the wrong `limit` (maybe 0). Check your source code.